# deploying flex on tomcat

Tags: apache-flex, tomcat, adapter, flash-builder

I am using Flash builder 4 (SDK3.5) to create my flex program.
I want to deploy this program and load it to a tomcat server.
I configure my "flex server" root folder and other parameters in the project properties.
The problem is, that i don't know how to make it generic. e.g. my friend's tomcat is installed in other directory on the computer. 
I know that in eclipse i can run the server and tomcat from the IDE. I can't see how i do it in Flash builder plugin for eclipse 4. 
There is a server configuration, but there isn't adapter for tomcat.
Any ideas?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the flex ant tasks to compile and deploy your swf. It offers the same functionality as Adobe Flex/Flash Builder, but it is more easy to configure for different environments. The tasks are basically wrappers for the commandline flex compiler

A good place to start is
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_ant_pt1.html

Furthermore. In your case with a server connection, you should take a look at the context.root and services property of the mcmlc ant task.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same confusion. My approach to this is like this.

Dont specify a server type while you create the flex project. In the compiler arguments you need to specify the "-services" and "-context-root".
-services will point to your services-config.xml. This can either be pointed from your eclipse workspace or copy and paste the all the required config files from the flex folder to any other location and link it from there. This is required only while compiling the flex project. So it needs to have the same destinations you use in your project.

-context-root would be your application name.

This makes it generic. you can use the swf in any server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the Server Adapters s by using the Intall New Software option and enter http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios. Then select the Web, XML, and Java EE Development and select the WST Server Adapters and the JST-Adapters (one of them includes Tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

First, configure server on Flash builder 4 and older is the same.
You can see how to do it [here](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Configuring_an_Application_Server_in_Eclipse.pdf)

Second, deploying your app on tomcat is not related to tomcat path on any computer, you just need to make sure its not the WebApp directory.

Now, can you explain in more details what is your problem exactly?